# Connecting to the database in UWP 10

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I'm getting an exception when trying to open a connection to the database using this code in a C# UWP 10 application on Visual Studio 2017:

```
    private readonly IDbConnection dbConnection;

    public SomeConstructor(SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb)
    {
        dbConnection = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());
        **dbConnection.Open();** //Exception is being thrown here
    }
```

Exception: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll

Exception Stacktrace:

> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at ProjectHelper.Database.DBHelper`1..ctor(SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb)
>      at MainProject.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()

I've tried playing with the references (removing and reinstalling them to the project), creating a new UWP 10 project on a new solution trying to connect and both ended up failing.

Is there anything that I'm missing maybe?

**EDIT**

I just found out that apparently UWP 10 doesn't allow for direct SQL connections and requires using alternatives/work-arounds to access a database.

Source: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-access-data-from-SQL-Server-database-in-Windows-Store-app

Comment: Is there any connection string or it is empty?

Comment: `sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = @"USER-PC",
            InitialCatalog = @"maindb",
            ConnectTimeout = 1000,
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };`

Comment: Can you connect with SQL Management Studio to the same `USER-PC` server? Maybe there is name for service like `SQLEXPRESS` => `USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Yes im able to connect via SQL Management Studio, I just found out that apparently UWP 10 doesn't allow for direct SQL connections and requires using alternatives/work-arounds to access a database.

Comment: @Sylar Instead of making an edit like that, you should write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that apparently UWP 10 doesn't allow for direct SQL connections and requires using alternatives/work-arounds to access a database.

Source: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-access-data-from-SQL-Server-database-in-Windows-Store-app